# Django: ProfileSerializer() takes no arguments

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the logged in user profile using django restframework api_view, i have written a simple logic to do that but it keeps showing this error that says `TypeError at /api/my-profile/2/ ProfileSerializer() takes no arguments`, i cannot really tell what is wrong with the code that i have written.

This is the code here

```
class MyProfileView(APIView):
    # queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk ,format=None):
        profile = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ProfileSerializer(profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
    path("my-profile/<int:pk>/", MyProfileView.as_view(), name="my-profile"),
```

serializer.py

```
class ProfileSerializer():
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image','full_name','bio','phone','dob','gender','country','state','city','address','longitude','latitude','zipcode','facebook','instagram','twitter','whatsApp',]
```

Comment: Share your `ProfileSerializer`.

Comment: I have updated the question With the profile serializers

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serializer must extend `serializers.ModelSerializer`, otherwise it is not really a serializer and doesn't know what to do with Meta class and its model.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image','full_name','bio','phone','dob','gender','country','state','city','address','longitude','latitude','zipcode','facebook','instagram','twitter','whatsApp',]
```

Take a look at [serializers docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)